# Moving SQL Server from XP to Win7 64bit

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

I am planning to move SQL Server 2008 R2 Express from XP 32bit to Windows 7 64bit, and I have following questions:

1. which version of SQL Server (2008 or 2012 , 32bit or 64bit) should I use on a Windows 7 PC?
2. how to move the database? Copy the `.mdf` files directly or backup and restore the databases on Windows 7, or generate database scripts from XP and then execute the script on Windows 7?
3. I used extremely openrowset microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0 statements in the script. On the Windows 7 PC, do I simple change the driver name to microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 in the script, then it will be ok?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> > *Which version of SQL Server (2008 or 2012, 32bit or 64bit)*

Since you're using **2008 R2** now, you can use **2008 R2**, **2012** or **2014** versions on your new machine. You cannot "go back" to an older version (like **2008**) without a lot of trouble.

Since the Express version has limitations, like only 1 GB can be used, I don't see much point in using a 64-bit version. I personally always use the 32-bit Express versions - even on Windows 7 x64.

> > *how to move the databases?*

The simplest would be to use backup & restore. Backup your databases on your existing PC into `.bak` files, copy those backups over to the new server, restore - done!

The backup&restore process reliably and easily copies everything *inside* the database - tables, views, stored procedures etc. but it does **not** move things that are defined on the **server-level** like logins and permissions